# I'm trying to place two tables side by side but I get an error

Tags: tables

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multirow}

\title{Test}
\author{Chad Stucki}
\date{September 2016}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

\begin{table}[!b]
\centering
\caption{Caption}
\begin{tabular}[t]{|c|c|}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\rule{0pt}{2.5ex} \textbf{Class I Fairing}} \\\hline
\rule{0pt}{2.5ex} \textbf{Configuration} & \textbf{Drag Ratio} \\\hline
\rule{0pt}{2.5ex} $\alpha = 61$ cm & \multirow{3}{*}{$D_R = 0.862$} \\\cline{1-1}
\rule{0pt}{2.5ex} $\beta = 0$ cm  & \\\cline{1-1}
\rule{0pt}{2.5ex} $\delta = 122$ cm & \\\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\rule{0pt}{2.5ex} \textbf{Reduction in Drag}} \\\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\rule{0pt}{2.5ex} $R_D = 13.8\%$} \\\hline
\end{tabular}
\begin{tabular}[t]{|c|c|}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\rule{0pt}{2.5ex} \textbf{Class II Fairing} \\\hline
\rule{0pt}{2.5ex} \textbf{Configuration} & \textbf{Drag Ratio} \\\hline
\rule{0pt}{2.5ex} $W = 73^{\circ}$ & \multirow{4}{*}{$D_R = 0.826$} \\\cline{1-1}
\rule{0pt}{2.5ex} $X = 49^{\circ}$ & \\\cline{1-1}
\rule{0pt}{2.5ex} $Y = 19^{\circ}$ & \\\cline{1-1}
\rule{0pt}{2.5ex} $Z = 32^{\circ}$ & \\\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\rule{0pt}{2.5ex} \textbf{Reduction in Drag}} \\\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\rule{0pt}{2.5ex} $R_D = 17.4\%$} \\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: There is a `}` missing after `\textbf{Class II Fairing}`. And you need `\usepackage{multirow}`.

Comment: Separately, do yourself a favor and (a) get rid of the multitude of `\rule{0pt}{2.5ex}` directives and instead (b) load the `array` package and issue the instruction (only once!) `\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}` immediately after `\begin{table}`.

Comment: You can achieve an effect similar to the \rule using \arraystretch ( see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31672/column-and-row-padding-in-tables/31704?s=1|0.0000#31704)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, facing that @StefanH found your missing `}`, and building on @Mico's solution, I tried expanding the topic, by refactoring your table. I added the following packages to your solution:

- `array` -> to have `\extrarowheight`
- `booktabs` -> for fancy rules
- `siunitx` to typeset units with the proper spacing.

Furthermore, in order to avoid the abundance of `$` I defined a new column type that automatically inserts that for you.

So, after a bit of clean up, here is the code, followed by the result. You will notice that I used fewer lines, since this way the information feel better grouped and more readable to me:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{array,booktabs,multirow}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\title{Test}
\author{Chad Stucki}
\date{September 2016}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{$}c<{$}}
\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

\begin{table}[!b]
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
\centering
\caption{Caption}
\begin{tabular}[t]{Cc}
\toprule
\multicolumn{2}{c}{ \textbf{Class I Fairing}} \\
 \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Configuration}} & \textbf{Drag Ratio} \\\midrule
 \alpha = \SI{61}{\centi\metre}& \multirow{3}{*}{$D_R = 0.862$} \\
 \beta = \SI{0}{\centi\metre} & \\
 \delta = \SI{122}{\centi\metre}& \\\midrule
\multicolumn{2}{c}{ \textbf{Reduction in Drag}} \\
\multicolumn{2}{c}{ $R_D = 13.8\%$} \\\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\begin{tabular}[t]{Cc}
\toprule
\multicolumn{2}{c}{ \textbf{Class II Fairing}} \\
 \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Configuration}} & \textbf{Drag Ratio} \\\midrule
 W = \ang{73} & \multirow{4}{*}{$D_R = 0.826$} \\
 X = \ang{49} & \\
 Y = \ang{19} & \\
 Z = \ang{32}& \\\midrule
\multicolumn{2}{c}{ \textbf{Reduction in Drag}} \\
\multicolumn{2}{c}{ $R_D = 17.4\%$} \\\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice answer. I would add on empty row to the first table, or even better, merge both table in one :). But this doesn't matter now, OP is not respond yet (after nine months :-( ).